# How to implement themoviedb api in javafx application

Tags: java, api, javafx

I have themoviedb.jar file,but I have no idea how to work with it?,I haven't worked with api's before,so help me with an example in general on how to work with api's in javaFX or specific themoviedb.jar api or suggest me any guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uwe Trottmann made a very good [wrapper around the tmdb api](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/tmdb-java).

From the documentation:

```
// Create an instance of the service you wish to use
// you can keep this around
Tmdb tmdb = new Tmdb();
tmdb.setApiKey("yourapikey");
MovieService movieService = tmdb.movieService();
//
// Call any of the available endpoints
Call<Movie> call = movieService.summary(550);
Movie movie = call.execute().body();
Call<Trailers> callTrailers = movieService.trailers(550);
Trailers trailers = callTrailers.execute().body();
```

Just check out the [test cases](https://github.com/UweTrottmann/tmdb-java/tree/master/src/test/java/com/uwetrottmann/tmdb2) to see how it works.

Comment: what is that apikey thing? and where to get it?

Comment: At the tmdb site. You have to get one in order to access any of their services.